# Cordova adaptive icons cause failed build: The "path" argument must be of type string

Tags: android, cordova

Trying to get adaptive icons working in a Cordova app (described [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/config_ref/images.html#adaptive-icon-with-colors) in the docs), but when I try to run `cordova run android`, the app never runs and the CLI just outputs this

```
Android Studio project detected
The "path" argument must be of type string
```

This is how I have the icon defined in `config.xml`

```
<platform name="android">
    <resource-file src="res/colors.xml" target="/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml" />
    <icon background="@color/background" density="hdpi" foreground="res/icon.png" />
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
```

And here is the contents of `colors.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="background">#191919</color>
</resources>
```

I know the issue has to do with the `icon` config because it only happens when I use `foreground` instead of `src`. This config works fine (but the icon isn't adaptive and has the default background color).

```
<platform name="android">
    <resource-file src="res/colors.xml" target="/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml" />
    <icon background="@color/background" density="hdpi" src="res/icon.png" />
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
```

Here are my relevant versions.

- node 9.11.2
- npm 5.6.0
- cordova 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
- cordova-android 7.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adaptive icons are only supported since cordova-android 8.0.0. See [here](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2019/02/16/cordova-android-release-8.0.0.html).

Comment: Thanks. It's strange that a feature that was in the docs last year was added in February this year.

Comment: Well the docs are marked as "in development", and are (even now) not the docs which are linked on the cordova homepage as far as I can see. However I agree that this is easy to miss and quite confusing.

Comment: I've always been confused by the cordova docs. I'm pretty sure I got to those docs by clicking a link in a "Outdated docs" banner on a different cordova docs site. Half the google results for "cordova [insert-feature-here]" lead to Phonegap or Ionic docs that are *almost* identical to the cordova docs.

Comment: you saved me man! cryptic error message and I tried this out on a whim and boom. working. thank you!!